# Facebook SDK for Android and iOS - Do i need a website ID to make a facebook like?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, native

I need to implement a Facebook like button inside native iOS and Android Apps. The like button is for a website (specifically, is for the apps' URLs in iTunes and PlayStore).

I don't like the webview approach, because of the pop-ups for fb login, etc.. So, i prefer using the Facebook SDK.

AFAIK, this can be achieved using the Graph API, with og.likes.

According to facebook developers page, in all the examples, the URL has an ID:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/og.likes/

```
//in this case, ID=226075010839791
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"http://samples.ogp.me/226075010839791", @"object",
                           nil
                       ];
```

**Question:** Do i need this ID? Can't i use a "simple" URL for my website? If it is really necessary, how do i get this ID?

**Additional question:** I also would like to show in the App how many Likes that website has. In this case, will i need that ID?

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID by entering your URL into the debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). At the bottom there is a url next to "Graph API" that looks like "http://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxx". The xxxxxx after the slash is the ID.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might need to create a Facebook App.  That is what the App ID you listed is.  Once you go to your Facebook Developer's page and create your app at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/async/create/dialog/, add your Android and iOS app bundle IDs to the Facebook App.  Then use the ID for your Facebook App.